# Disabling window.ondeviceorientation after first iteration

Tags: javascript

I have an event handler that is executed only after a specific condition is met, as seen in the pseudo code below:

```
if(condition)
{
    window.ondeviceorientation = function(e){
        //my code
    }
}
```

I only need this to run once to capture the gyroscope values and set some sessionStorage values.

How do I disable the `ondeviceorientation` loop after the first iteration? Here's what I'm currently doing, but not sure it's the best solution:

```
if(condition)
{
    var stop_event_loop;
    window.ondeviceorientation = function(e){
        if(stop_event_loop) break;
        //my code

        stop_event_loop = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply clear out the event handler, like this:

```
if(condition)
{
    window.ondeviceorientation = function(e){
      //my code
      window.ondeviceorientation = null;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The function doesn't seem to run again when I reload the page, why is that?!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your target browsers, I would recommend using the appropriate DOM-spec implementation for hitching functions to events, and then make sure you're stopping the handling of the event elsewhere.

So for the DOM 2 spec, you would use the EventTarget.addEventListener(); function to add something like:

window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', eventHandler, onCapture);

Then from within the event handler, you should check for and use the "e.preventDefault()" function to stop the code from executing if the "stop_event_loop" flag has been set to true, as well as return false to handle browser-specific implementations of event propagation.

Although, keep in mind that the scope of that "stop_event_loop" variable means it will be instantiated every time you step into that conditional block of code, so it will always be false when that function is tied to the event. If that's a close approximation to your current implementation, that's probably why your code is triggered every time the event is fired. You need to move that variable declaration somewhere where it will be a bit more permanent. I recommend NOT using the global scope, but anywhere outside of that conditional block should prevent it from being re-instantiated every time that function would trigger.

So your code would look like:

```
//elsewhere in your code
var stop_event_loop;

//your event loop
if(condition)
{
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', eventHandler, onCapture);

    var eventHandler = function (e) {
        if (stop_event_loop) {
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            return false;
        } else {
           //your code
        }
    }
}
```